# Call a Group Object by Name in ForEach Loop

Tags: arrays, csv, powershell, foreach, group-by

I've imported a CSV file into an array and grouped it by email address.  I'd like to be able to call the group by name in another ForEach loop so that I can send an email to each email address with a table of the $ServerID(s) and $DateTime(s) associated with them.  Was Group-Object the best way to start this?

In the CSV file, one email address can be associated with many servers, but one server is only associated with one email address.  The values in the file will be updated constantly - thus the need for dynamic variables for almost all objects.

```
$csv = import-csv "C:Example.csv"

$array = @()

ForEach ($server in $csv) {

        $object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{"Email"= $server.Email; "ServerID" = $server.ServerID; "DateTime" = $server.DateTime}

        $array += $object}

$array | Group-Object Email


Count      Name                                 Group

2       A@gmail.com     {@{PG_Email=A@gmail.com; ServerID=333; Lease_End=10/10/15}, @{PG_Email=A@gmail.com; ServerID=111; Lease_End=12/12/15}}                                                               
1       B@gmail.com     {@{PG_Email=B@gmail.com; ServerID=222; Lease_End=09/09/15}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should use `Group-Object`. I'm not sure what you mean with "call the group by name". If you want to select a group based by the name you would have to save the result from `Group-Object` and search for your group like:

```
$groups = $array | Group-Object Email
$selectedmail = "B@gmail.com"
$groups | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $selectedmail }
```

Or you could save the groups in a hashtable:

```
#Create hashtable
$ht = @{}
#Fill hashtable with groups (email as key/ID)
$array | Group-Object Email | ForEach-Object { $ht[$_.Name] = $_.Group }

$selectedmail = "B@gmail.com"
#Get objects for selected mail
$ht[$selectedmail]
```

If you are going to mail everyone, I would simplify this to:

```
Import-Csv "C:\Example.csv" |
Group-Object Email |
ForEach-Object {
    $to = $_.Name

    #Get table of ServerID + Lease_End as string to send as mailbody
    $mailbody = $_.Group | Format-Table -Property ServerID, Lease_End -AutoSize | Out-String

    #You could also create a HTML-table with:
    $htmlbody = $_.Group | Select-Object -Property ServerID, Lease_End | ConvertTo-HTML -Property Name, Length

    #Send mail
    #Send-MailMessage -To $to -Subject "Lease-status" -Body $mailbody -From "mysupersecret@mail.com"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Frode for the detailed response. Yes, by "calling the group by name" I meant saving and searching as you guessed.  Your first solution should work great as long as the $selectedemail can be dynamic.  Would I create a separate array of distinct email addresses from the CSV to loop through?  Trust me, I  wish this email could be sent to everyone, but unfortunately it calls for emailing each separately. Thanks for your patience - I just started with Powershell a couple weeks ago.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need to loop an array if you're not going to send to everyone (looping usually means you don't have a specific one or know who to send to). Anyways. you don't need to create another array. You could use `$groups.Name` or `$ht.keys` depending on which solution you use to list all the emails. A variable is always dynamic (change it in code, replace it with a function parameter etc.), that's why I used the variable so that the code is depending on the variable and not one specific address. :-)

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks, Frode!

Comment: No problem. Remember to mark the correct answer when you decide so the question can be "closed"